Positive Constant in Lindbladian
Consider the following Lindbladian
$$
L \left[X \right] = i \left[H, X \right] + \gamma \left( 2QXQ - \left(Q^2X + XQ^2 \right)   \right),
$$
where X is observable, in other words, Heisenberg picture. $Q$ is self-adjoint operator, I have not written the most general form of Lindbladian, but this form is sufficient to ask the question. From which requirements the condition $\gamma > 0$ follows? Consider the situation when $\gamma$ is purely imaginary $\gamma = i y$, $y \in R$. What from the point of view of quantum mechanics can be said about this system?

If $\gamma$ is complex $L[X]$ is not Hermitian, which implies that $X + \delta t L[X]$ is not Hermitian, so time evolution would not preserve Hermitisity

The requirement that $\gamma$ is nonnegative requires some mathematical rigor to prove and will be lengthy to write out here. See section 3.3.1 of this book, right below Eq. (3.143), and the derivation leading to it. This book might also be useful.

A handwaving argument I like to make is that "$\gamma$ represents the strength of the interaction between the system and the environment involving the operator $\hat{Q}$", so it should be nonnegative.
